# Troubleshooting Maytag Neptune TL Washer

Tags: washing-machine

Appliance: Maytag Neptune TL Washer Model Number 62908580

### Problem

So, this happened after the power cycled at my home, which means something's definitely blown in there.  However I cannot figure out what it is.

1. The system is stuck on Code 61 by default and a few others when the various buttons are pressed.

Code 61, nor the other codes that show up are listed in the Troubleshooting Guide.  Also not all the keys work even though the membrane seems to be sending the right signals

### Diagnosis so far

1. Unplugging the appliance for several hours (days) does not reset it (no miracle internal fix, or a capacitance issue)
2. Replaced the Machine Control Board (which was my first thought) with a brand new one, however the outputs and the button control behavior has not changed
3. Unplugged all the controls from the MCB with the exception of the Line RF filter and the code still remains the same

Can anyone help?

Comment: Acording to the Manuel 5-7 is not used, have you tried clearing the code, the manual states pressing delay start + chime for 3 seconds will clear the code. 1 is a drain issue I know my daughters washer failed and it had a filter prior to the pump that was full of anamial hair and pine needles, I cleaned that out and it worked fine.

Comment: I ended up dumping the washing machine and buying a new one :'( but I'll leave the question up in case someone else has a similar issue!